# mean square value of rayleigh distribution

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, random, simulation

I'm reading a paper which suggests that using random numbers with Rayleigh distribution are necessary to get a good result. 
from what I can see the only parameter of the Rayleigh distribution is the scale, theta.

However, the parameter they have specified to be used is in terms of the 'mean square', ie.

> generate c from a Rayleigh distribution with mean square value of 2S(fn)Af

*`(numerical simulation of a random sea: a common error and its effect upon wave group statistics, Tucker, Challenor and Carter)`*

I don't really understand this. How can I choose the mean square value of the distribution? If I google mean square stuff about the mean squared error comes up, but I am not trying to calculate an error since I am not trying to compare how the distribution fits against some data set, I'm trying to generate values.

Can anyone help me out? Is the mean square value the MSE and I just have to do some reverse engineering? or is it something else entirely? Is it literally the square of the mean?

Answer (score 1):

What the paper seems to say is:

> Random $a_n$ and $b_n$ are generated from a Gaussian distribution with variance $S(f_n) \Delta f$ ....  An alternative is to generate $c_n$ from a Rayleigh distribution with mean square value of $2S(f_n) \Delta f$ and $\phi_n$ from a uniform distribution $(0, 2\pi)$

It is called the *mean square value* because $\mathbb E(c_n^2) = 2S(f_n) \Delta f$, being $\mathbb E(a_n^2+b_n^2)=\mathbb E(a_n^2) + \mathbb E(b_n^2)$, so the expected value or mean of the square of $c_n$,  but not the rather smaller square of the mean

For the Rayleigh distribution, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) uses a scale parameter called $\sigma$ and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RayleighDistribution.html) a scale parameter called $s$.  In this context they would both be $\sqrt{S(f_n) \Delta f}$ so without the $2$